# Express routes with Socket IO Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

I'm creating a microservice with **NodeJS** which will send & receive messages with `socketIO`. I'm following a boilerplate and setup the `GET` & `POST` routes with `ExpressRouter`

```js
socket.on('sendmessage', (newMessage) => {
    socket.in(userId).emit('newmessage', newMessage);
});
```

```js
app.post('/sendMessage', expressAsyncHandler(async function (req, res) {
  // saving the message to database and returning a response....
}))
```

I'm just confused about why do I need `routes` if I can handle all data saving, validation and authorization functionality too in `socketIO` code block? What is the best case for an application like that which ensures message delivery and no data loss?

Answer (score 0):

Whether to use routes or not depends on the design and architecture of your application. If you need to implement additional functionality outside of sending and receiving messages, such as authentication or data validation, using routes with Express is a good option. If your application is solely focused on sending and receiving messages, then you can handle the functionality within the socket.on() event.

For ensuring message delivery and avoiding data loss, you can implement message acknowledgment or implement a message queue like RabbitMQ or Apache Kafka to buffer messages before they are processed by the server. This helps ensure that messages are not lost even if the server goes down or there is a connection issue.

Comment: Yeah I need the data validation and authentication but I can do that too in socketIO code block.

Comment: For message delivery I'm using Redis with sockeIO.